# Whether to distinguish the plural form "Dinge (as physical objects)" from "Dinger (as figurative matters)"?

Tags: word-choice

> Jetzt kannst du noch aufregendere **Dinge** herstellen.
>
> {or}: Jetzt kannst du noch aufregendere **Dinger** herstellen.

As I understand it, there are two different sets of plural forms of the noun *Ding*. I read somewhere that when you have the meaning of "tangible, physical objects" in mind, you should opt for *Dinger*, whereas *Dinge* supposedly denotes "figurative matters (*Angelegenheit*)".

In the example sentence above, the speaker obviously talks about physical objects, given the presence of the verb *herstellen* (produce). So I'm tempted to go for *Dinger*, but the speaker uses *Dinge* instead. I wonder why?

Comment: Don't read somewhere, use dictionaries instead.

Comment: @userunknown Hi. Actually, this *somewhere* happens to be in a dictionary. http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/allemand-anglais/Ding/10340

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't find "tangible, physical objects" on that page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Dinger* is used colloquially for concrete objects (and, as your dictionary and another answer point out, for young women, even though I am not sure that that use deserves a separate entry, one might also hope that it has mostly fallen out of use). Your text does not use *Dinger*, because it is not colloquial. In colloquial speech one maybe would not use *Dinge* either, because the things in question are not specific enough. Maybe one would use *Sachen* at that language level.

Answer (score 1):

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ding_Gegenstand_Vorgang#Bedeutung3)
lists "Dinger" as plural form of "Ding" when used as synonym for girl.

Physical objects are called Dinge (as stated in your caption).

I would suggest not to use "Dinger". I found one sentence using "Dinger":

> Ich möchte nicht das Gefühl haben, dass ich auf die ganzen Dinger aufpassen muss, weil ... <sup>[dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=333648&idForum=1&lang=de&lp=ende)</sup>

But I would say, that here it is used as deprecative plural form of the word "Ding".

Comment: While the plural of "Ding" used for "Mädchen" is *always* "Dinger", there's lots of case where you'd (at least colloquially) use "Dinger" in the plural. So I wouldn't use this as a criterion. :-)

Comment: Not at least, but at most.

Comment: Duden also has "Dinger" for 1b.